# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Tkinter' error although it has always worked

Tags: tkinter, modulenotfounderror

I can no longer use the Tkinter module. Before I switched to Python 3, the script started without any problems. Now this error appears:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Tkinter'
```

Can you help me solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be careful, you must use tkinter for Python 3 and Tkinter for Python 2.

So, if you're using Python 3, the module has been renamed to tkinter.